# Phonegap + iOS + Parse Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, parse-platform

I am developing Cordova based app for iOS and android
I have successfully implemented Parse for Android.
I have a HandleGlobalPush in my index.html which i call from CordovaActivity.java when Parse notification arrives and users taps on it.
I handle my view navigation in HandleGlobalPush which redirects user to specific screen/view based on AlertType data received in notification
Working fine without any issue.

Yesterday i started for iOS for doing the same
This is what i implemented in AppDelegate.m

```
 -(void) application :(UIApplication *)application
 didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
 {
     // Process the remote notification
     [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];

     // Clear notification badge
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];


     //here data will be json and converted to string in future

     NSString *jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HandleGlobalPush('data');"];
     //[self.viewController.loadFromString("javascript:" + jsCallBack);
     [viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

}
```

I can see everything working i can reach till viewController.webView i can see the jsCallBack generated as well. I also see the data received in Push But it is not calling HandleGlobalPush from where i will be doing to view navigation and UI changes based on data..

Answer (score 0):

@Sandy,
 I understand what you are doing - but not why. Parse has just released new SDKs for iOS and Android. And in any case, there are already *Push Plugin* for Parse. Are you trying to build a new Plugin? Is so, there are already instructs for that, and you are off base.

[Phonegap FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/) - see last question

*Introducing Parse Push for OS X*
http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-parse-push-for-os-x/

Google: [phonegap push plugin parse](https://www.google.com/search?q=phonegap+push+plugin+parse)

[Phonegap Parse Plugin](https://www.parse.com/questions/push-notification-with-phonegap-plugin-using-javascript)

In addition, if you are writing Java, that defeats the entire purpose of Phonegap, unless you are writing a plugin.

Google: [phonegap how to write a plugin](https://www.google.com/search?q=phonegap+how+to+write+a+plugin)

Comment: Hello Jesse,  Thanks for your help. I tried with PushPlugin i was able to register the device but not able to get the push from Parse. I saw lots of warning about deprecation in iOS 8 or later. But one thing i found out from that plugin is for parsing json data to json string in objective c and how to pass it function call back in javascript. I took that logic in implemented in my code shown above and it worked after that. So my main problem is resolved. Parse Plugin is also doing the same thing in plugin so i am good by modifying appdelegate.m of cordova project.

Comment: Continue... Right now i am in testing phase so once entire api is logic is done we will be writing native app so we will take care of it at that time